# Bad Image Format exception between 32bit and 64bit Machines

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, ibm-midrange

We have a winforms appliction that has to talk to an AS400.   To do this we imported the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries classes in the Winforms application and have IBM System I Access for Windows on our machines. It must have the System I Access or it will not talk to the AS/400. Everything works fine on my 64bit development machine.  It also works fine on the client's 64bit machine.  However when we attempt to install it on a 32bit machine we get a Bad Image format exception.  We tried making just an x86 installer instead of any cpu but that did not work (same bad image exception).  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have x86 client libraries in addition to the x64 ones?

Comment: yes we do.  We made sure the client had the 32bit version of installed on his machine.  At first we attempted to include the IBM.Data.DB2.Iseries dll with the installer but that did not work.

Comment: Pretty classical IBM problem.  That company survives from support calls.

Comment: http://gcn.com/Articles/2009/07/09/5-Tips-for-Developing-with-64-Bit-Windows.aspx   QUOTE: To solve the bad image exception problems, change the target platform on all your assemblies to "Any CPU." If for some reason you aren't able to do that -- perhaps because an assembly is supplied without source -- then set all your assemblies to the same platform, either x86 or x64. If you have .Net 1.0 or 1.1 assemblies, it's best to recompile them with .NET 2.0. If you can't recompile the .Net 1.0 or 1.1 assemblies, then compile your other code set to the x86 platform so that it is compatible.

Comment: I have a doubt, you talk about x86 `installer`. You mean you have changed the configuration (Via Configuration Manager) of each assembly to x86, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you have compiled your program to 32-bit, somewhere it is still trying to load a 64-bit dll. Since you say that the 3rd party dll's are 32bit, what is left are your own dll's.

You can verify that by setting the solution platform to x86. Then check all your projects (exe and dll) if they are set to x86. I suspect one of them has a platform target set to x64. You check them by right clicking Project, select Properties, Build-tab -> Platform Target.

Also make sure that all dlls are actually set to Build in the Configuration Manager (Select "Configuration Manager..." from the Solution Platforms dropdown in the menubar.

Comment: found the x64 dll that we didn't know was there

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure what's wrong with your assembly, but my advice would be to try a [PE file validator](http://www.woodmann.com/forum/entry.php?55-PE-Validator-Script) and [check the magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757512/about-the-magic-number-of-pe) of the executable and dynamic library files from your build.

Specifically, see if each file begins with `0x10b` or `0x20b` as a first check before performing deeper validation. You can do this easily with a tool like the (now-discontinued) [PEiD](http://www.peid.info/).

As mentioned in the errata, it's exceedingly likely that one of your binaries is 64-bit when you were expecting 32. This would be easiest to find by using [a debugger that can resolve dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OllyDbg), though this may not be legally tractable.